# cannot access gitlab with my own url

Tags: apache, gitlab, virtualhost

I'm tried to install gitlab on my own network and access it with my url ie git.myname.com using apache virtual host . I installed gitlab omnibus and then changed the gitlab.rb with -

> external_url 'http://git.myname.com'
>
> web_server['external_users'] = ['www-data']
>
> ngingx['enable']=false

and then edited `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` like -

```
#LogLevel alert rewrite:trace6
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[\w\.-]+/[\w\.-]+/repository/archive [OR]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api/v3/projects/.*/repository/archive [OR]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[\w\.-]+/[\w\.-]+/(info/refs|git-upload-pack|git-receive-pack)$
#RewriteRule .* http://localhost:8081%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA]

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName git.myname.com
  ServerSignature Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On

  <Location />
    Require all granted

    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8080
    ProxyPassReverse http://git.myname.com/
  </Location>

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1:8080%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA]

  # needed for downloading attachments
  DocumentRoot /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public

</VirtualHost>
```

The gitlab is accessable with `localhost:8080` but `git.myname.com` always leads to internal server error with gitlab logo. `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start` doesnt do the charm. I even have created `gitlab.conf` with same script but still the issue. How do i solve this issue ?

The `/var/log/apache2/error.log` says

> AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL / (scheme 'http').
>   If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy
>   submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured out the issue. If you are trying to do the same in future, the above is pretty much what you need to follow for hosting the gitlab server with your own url. The issue is fixed by running the following commands

```
sudo a2enmod proxy_html
sudo a2enmod proxy
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo a2enmod proxy_balancer
sudo a2enmod proxy_connect
sudo a2enmod proxy_html
sudo a2enmod proxy_headers
sudo a2enmod headers
sudo a2enmod proxy_ajp

sudo systemctl restart apache2
```